# When are incompressible surfaces isotopic into a two-skeleton?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Haken proved that an incompressible surface in a triangulated irreducible 3-manifold is isotopic to a surface which is *normal* with respect to the triangulation ([Theorie der Normalflächen. Acta Math. 105 1961 245–375](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=IID&s1=79845&vfpref=html&r=29&mx-pid=141106)).

While normal surfaces are tremendously useful, I want my surfaces to be isotopic into the two-skeleton and I am unsure when I can conclude that they indeed are isotopic into the two-skeleton.
I suspect that there are triangulated 3-manifolds out there containing incompressible surfaces which are not isotopic into the two-skeleton, but I am hoping that if the 3-manifold has a metric and the tetrahedra are "small enough" compared to the injectivity radius of the 3-manifold, then incompressible surfaces can be isotoped into the two-skeleton.

Can someone point me to a reference or explain whether or not there are reasonable properties of a triangulation which imply that incompressible surfaces are isotopic into the two-skeleton?

Comment: Note that Haken's theorem need the 3-manifold to be irreducible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't always expect every incompressible surface to be isotoped into the $2$-skeleton. There are only finitely many subsets of the $2$-skeleton, but there can be infinitely many nonparallel incompressible surfaces. This is simplest in the $3$-torus, but there are many other examples. Jaco's stair construction gives incompressible surfaces of arbitrarily high genus in a surface (of positive genus) times a circle.

Comment: Is there any nontrivial example where the incompressible surfaces do isotope into the two-skeleton? Is there a classification of such manifolds?

Comment: I guess the non-Haken manifolds (perhaps irreducible ones) are what you are calling trivial. I'm not sure when there are only finitely many isotopy classes of $\pi_1$-injective surfaces. Any nice enough triangulation of such a manifold should work. 

Comment: Does this work?  Suppose the surface $S$ is separating (which is the case I'm actually interested in).  Let $U$ be the union of tetrahedra which intersect $S$.  Some boundary component $B$ of $U$ must be separating.  The problem is that $B$ might not be isotopic to $S$ if $B$. It might look like a copy of $S$ which intersects itself in some set of vertices, edges, or faces.  In this case we can take two barycentric subdivisions and push $B$ into the two skeleton of the subdivision so that it is embedded and isotopic to $S$.  

Comment: @bb: Your original question posited a fixed underlying triangulation. If instead you fix the surface $S$ and allow yourself to pick and choose amongst triangulations, then certainly you can produce a triangulation into which $S$ may be isotoped. Nonetheless, as Zare's answer shows, for a typical 3-manifold there will not exist any one triangulation into which all incompressible surfaces can be isotoped.

Comment: @bb: It sounds like you are trying to construct a triangulation from a surface so that the surface is in the $2$-skeleton. If so, just triangulate the $3$-manifold with boundary you get by cutting along $S$, and add a few tetrahedra to make the two triangulations of $S$ consistent. Your construction seems to make some strong assumptions about how $S$ intersects the particular triangulation you have at the start. You can see that this construction has to make some assumptions, since there are only finitely many subsets of the $2$-skeleton of any fixed iteration of barycentric subdivision...

Comment: @bb: More explicitly, what do you do if the surface intersects every tetrahedron of your original triangulation? 

Comment: I'll try to explain my situation more clearly and completely.  $S$ is a closed surface in the non-compact $S \times (0,1)$. I do not get to choose the triangulation and I want to say that $S$ is isotopic into the 2-skeleton of the 2nd barycentric subdivision of the given triangulation. Some boundary component $B$ of the union $U$ must be separating. I want to say that if $B$ is not isotopic to $S$, then $B$ is just a copy of $S$ which intersects itself in a set of vertices, edges, and faces. We can push $B$ into the 2-skeleton of the 2nd barycentric subdivision to get rid of the intersections.

Comment: Do you have a triangulation of $S\times (0,1)$ with infinitely many tetrahedra, or are you just taking the interior of a (finite) triangulation of $S\times [0,1]$? In the second case you are done: the boundary of the regular neighborhood of $S \times 0$ in the triangulation is always isotopic to $S$, and if you start with a 2nd barycentric subdivision you are sure that it does not intersect $S\times 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Bruno. I have a triangulation with infinitely many tetrahedra. I should have said that some boundary component $B$ of $U$ separates the ends of $S \times (0,1)$, not just separates. $B$ is the boundary of an open set containing $S$. If we're lucky, the open set is a regular neighborhood. Otherwise $B$ has some extra genus or intersections which come from the open set "bumping into itself." I want to say that we can get rid of the extra genus or intersections by using the 2-skeleton of the 2nd barycentric subdivision. It looks like I have some more thinking to do.